# PHP Create array where duplicate elements from other array are keys

Tags: php, html, arrays

So, I've got an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] = Array
        (
            [miasto] = Tarnów
            [ulica] = ul. Kościuszki 120
            [link] = <a class="cfs-hyperlink" href="/strona-w-budowie" target="_blank"><span class="text"></span></a>
        )

    [1] = Array
        (
            [miasto] = Tarnów
            [ulica] = ul. Pułaskiego 12
            [link] = <a class="cfs-hyperlink" href="/strona-w-budowie" target=""><span class="text"></span></a>
        )

    [2] = Array
        (
            [miasto] = Kraków
            [ulica] = ul. Test 12
            [link] = <a class="cfs-hyperlink" href="/strona-w-budowie" target=""><span class="text"></span></a>
        )

)
```

So from this array, I would like to create an array that will merge same first element and give them single value of this link with text of second value, so it would be like this:

```
Array
(
    [Tarnów] = Array
        (
            [0] = <a class="cfs-hyperlink" href="/strona-w-budowie" target="_blank"><span class="text">ul. Kościuszki 120</span></a>
            [1] = <a class="cfs-hyperlink" href="/strona-w-budowie" target="_blank"><span class="text">ul. Pułaskiego 12</span></a>
        )

    [Kraków] = Array
        (
            [0] = <a class="cfs-hyperlink" href="/strona-w-budowie" target="_blank"><span class="text">ul. Test 12</span></a>

        )

)
```

Sorry if question is not so specific, but I could not fin anywhere how to even name something like this in google and stack's search. Please be kind and even just a little nod how in the World I should look for something as bizzare as this.

EDIT: Adding my code:
 pastebin.com/jrDZLAnZ

Comment: So, have you tried anything or just wait for code?

Comment: Of course I tried, but I'm not pretty good yet. I can show the code here: https://pastebin.com/jrDZLAnZ

Comment: Your code __must be__ posted here. Please read [ask] and [tour] to be more familiar with this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input array is `$arr` you can use this

```
$result = array();

foreach ($arr as $val)
{
    $b = explode('</span></a>' , $val['link']);
    $result[$val['miasto']][] = $b[0] .  $val['ulica'] . '</span></a>';
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Dayum man, that is awesome. Looks really good and most important works. But still there is no $val['ulica'] inside $val['link'] span. can you help with that too? I could propably explode somehow this in code. Becouse I would love end result to be ul li with two levels.

Comment: Man, you are a saint. I have tried to do something with this for like 4h.